# Load lottery drawings from file like this way in python?

Tags: python, file

I want to create a python script to analyze and generate lottery prediction numbers based on already done drawings.
For this I need first to load lottery drawings from a text file into some kind of python container (I don't know yet if a list is the best one).
The text file is like follow:

```
08-08-93 38 17 47 25 30 37
15-08-93 6 7 30 17 2 42
22-08-93 44 20 17 3 38 45
29-08-93 42 30 36 5 4 6
05-09-93 5 14 7 49 35 19
12-09-93 42 28 41 15 22 38
19-09-93 18 4 16 35 2 17
03-10-93 44 48 34 37 4 41
17-10-93 13 7 6 45 29 25
24-10-93 8 22 43 14 34 15
31-10-93 14 17 47 19 36 12
14-11-93 48 20 6 43 4 35
```

First one is the date which can have different format (yy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy etc.) and after that follow the numbers.
I want to analyze easily just the numbers to do e.g. average, sum, stdev etc. and based on this I want to generate other lottery combinations with the same specifications. 
I would like to have/keep the date for each drawing in order to access it faster when I need e.g. print draw from 14-11-83 or the script itself should say to me something like: "general average is xx.xx and yy drawings fall out of this range, they are: "date: 14-11-93: num1, num2, num3 etc. and 23-09-14: num1, num2, num3 etc."
That's why I want to keep the date but also to use a container which is easy to loop through.
something like:

```
list a = ['date', int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5, int num6]
```

but when looping it should skip the date (first element a[0]).
Other way I think is a dictionary but is it so easy to loop all of that ?

I tried a few other pieces of code from here but seems to not work:

```
with open('lotto.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    # you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
    content = [x.strip('') for x in content]
    print content
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with open('lotto.txt') as f:
     line = f.readline()
     a = line.split()
```

`a` will now be the list as you requested.

Comment: WoW ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: But it shows just for the first line: ['08-08-93', '38', '17', '47', '25', '30', '37']
I need something like a list of lists, something like: [['08-08-93', '38', '17', '47', '25', '30', '37'], ['09-08-93', '34', '14', '447', '5525', '230', '337'], ['10-08-93', '33', '27', '437', '525', '830', '137'] and so on] and I want to loop faster through them because I want to analyze just the numbers not the date, date will be just for quick access to a specified/needed drawing. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I thought with a dictionary would be much easy but as I can see you shown to me a very easy method too.

Comment: Then simply keep an extra list outside of the loop, something like lines_list = [], and then add lines_list.append(a) in each iteration of the loop.